# svn post-commit shell script permission errors

Tags: bash, shell, svn, post-commit

I have written my first shell script which goes like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# This is a custom post-commit for sending email
# when an svn repo is changed.
#

repodir=$1
revision=$2

author=`/usr/bin/svnlook author  -r $revision $repodir`
date=`/usr/bin/svnlook   date    -r $revision $repodir`
log=`/usr/bin/svnlook    log     -r $revision $repodir`
info=`/usr/bin/svnlook   changed -r $revision $repodir`

url="http://www.mydomain.net/svn/filesystem/$repo"

echo 'To: me@googlemail.com' > commit-message   **<<LINE17**
echo 'From: me@mydomain.net' >> commit-message
echo 'Subject: SVN Commit' >> commit-message
echo '' >> commit-message
echo 'repository  -  $url' >> commit-message
echo 'date        -  $date' >> commit-message
echo 'username    -  $author' >> commit-message
echo 'revision    -  $revision' >> commit-message
echo 'comment     -  $log' >> commit-message
echo 'test email' >> commit-message
echo '$info' >> commit-message

ssmtp me@googlemail.com < commit-message

rm commit-message
```

When i run a test (with the svn vars stripped out) logged in as me on the server:   ./post-commit
The script runs fine, it writes the commit file to disk and uses in conjunction with sSMTP, and i receive an email in gmail.

However when I commit a file with svn I am getting permission errors.

The thing is I have chmod'd the parent dir to 777.

```
post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
/home/svn/filesystem/hooks/post-commit: line 17: commit-message: Permission denied
```

When I try to see which user is running commits by wiping the post-commit script to:

```
echo $USER
```

It doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a temporary file just use a here document instead. Also, using single quotes won't allow your variable to be expanded:

```
ssmtp me@googlemail.com <<EOF
To: me@googlemail.com
From: me@mydomain.net
Subject: SVN Commit

repository  -  $url
date        -  $date
username    -  $author
revision    -  $revision
comment     -  $log
test email
$info
EOF
```

The problem by the way because the svn user has no write access to your current directory, or probably another directory on runtime.

More info about here documents [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), and more info about quoting [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html).

A [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) is actually another similar solution but I believe a here document is more appropriate here.